# How to export global variable with modified values when using parallelization in R with parSapply()

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am using parSapply from the "parallel" package in R to optimize a computationally expensive code. The code works well and the final answer is the same as the serial version of my code. The only problem is that I have a global variable whose values are changing during the code, but parSapply function can not apply the changes on the global variables. Here is a simple example:

```
M = matrix(1,5,5)
test = function(x){
M[x,x] <<- x
}

sapply(c(1:5), function(x) test(x))
M
no_of_cores = detectCores()
cl = makeCluster(no_of_cores)
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c("test","M"), envir=environment())
parSapply(cl, c(1:5), function(x) test(x))
M
```

when I use sapply function, the values of M are modified correctly, but when I use parSapply, M does not change! I appreciate any suggestions to fix this issue! Thanks.

Comment: @akrun the second link suggests: "I would create RDS files on disk storing what you want with names using the PID of each worker (Sys.getpid())". I do not know how to do that?

Comment: @akrun oh, I tried that, but it did not work since I have a matrix, not a one-dimensional variable. test = function(x){
  assign('M[x,x]',x,envir = globalenv()) 
}

Comment: @akrun thanks! ` M[x, x] <- x; assign("M", M, .GlobalEnv)` works on this simple example, but it makes my main code very slow! Do you know what might be the bottleneck?

Comment: @akrun thanks for your help

Comment: @akrun So, you mean I should return the row and column indexes and also the updated values and at the end assign the values to the corresponding locations?

Comment: @akrun this works, but again since the size of the matrix is so big, it is not efficient.

Comment: @akrun For a tiny part of my data, here is the results: the last method takes 1.708832 mins (when I update the matrix out of the parallelization). When I use "<<- " it does not update the matrix but it takes 5.565088 secs. using M[x, x] <- x; assign("M", M, .GlobalEnv) was very slow, I wait more than 7 mins but it did not finish.

Comment: @akrun I need this result for the next step of my code.

Comment: @akrun yes, exactly! but timing is very important for me since I have a big matrix.

Comment: @akrun but without parallelization, it takes 1 min! I need to make it faster since I need to repeat it again and again and also this timing is for a tiny part of my data.

Comment: @akrun thanks! it works, but there is another problem. when I request several nodes, it seems some of the nodes failed to report their results: "In mclapply(argsList, FUN, mc.preschedule = preschedule, mc.set.seed = set.seed,  :
  scheduled cores ..... did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `foreach`

```
library(doSNOW)
library(parallel)
no_of_cores = detectCores()
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(no_of_cores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
M <- matrix(1,5,5)

comb <- function(m, ...) {
  for (r in list(...)) {
    m[r$k, r$k] <- r$k
  }
  m
}

out <- foreach(k=1:5, .combine='comb', .init=M,
          .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
    m <- M  
     list(k=k, m=m)
  }
```

-output

```
out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    3    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    4    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    5
```